# Removing some characters in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem on replacing this value "..." by NaN. Here is my code

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls')
    del energy['Unnamed: 0']
    del energy['Unnamed: 1']
    energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
    energy.replace("...", np.NaN)  
    energy['Energy Supply']
```

They always appear :

```
Out[46]:
17      321
18      102
19     1959
20      ...
21        9
       ... 
241     344
242     400
243     480
244     NaN
245     NaN
Name: Energy Supply, Length: 229, dtype: objec
```

Anyone can help me solve this ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, please tell us what you expect on the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that replace returns a DataFrame by defaulft (see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)).
To solve this you can either

```py
energy = energy.replace("...", np.NaN)
```

or

```py
energy.replace("...", np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

You can even avoid this problem altogether by specifying that "..." should be interpreted as NaN at read time:

```py
energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls", na_values="...")
```

See [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `...` goes with leading/trailing spaces. And also, you should check if they are one three-dot character or `...`. If your supply is numerical as shown, you can do:

```
energy['Energy Supply'] = pd.to_numeric(energy['Energy Supply'], errors='coerce')
```